# Reportlab tables: add make a table cell consume flowables like frame does

Tags: reportlab

I'm using reportlab and platypus for generating PDF reports.
Since I have a complex page formatting, i'm using tables to define grid.
What I want to do is to draw more than one flowable inside cell, so cell will just draw them top to bottom.
I have tried to use "KeepTogether" but it says "too large on page...", looks like there is a bug in space calculation in KeepTogether.
Is there any way to do combine number of flowables in one cell?
Thanks.